# How to perform Load / Performance testing on website which using Okta Authentication?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load, okta

How to perform Load / Performance testing on website which using Okta Authentication  ?
I am able to use JMeter for this test or it will give me error ?
Did anyone done this kind of test with another tool or  ?

I have done some test but never use and I dont know how to use if the website have Okta Authentication

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Okta might have many faces and as long as your website doesn't use [Okta's MFA](https://www.okta.com/products/adaptive-multi-factor-authentication/) it should be possible to authenticate/authorize using JMeter.

As per [Okta documentation](https://OAuth%202.0%20and%20OpenID%20Connect%20Overview):

> There are two main types of authentication that you can perform with Okta:
>
> - The [OpenID Connect](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/) (OIDC) protocol is built on the OAuth 2.0 protocol and helps authenticate users and convey information about them. It's also more opinionated than plain OAuth 2.0, for example in its scope definitions.
> - The [OAuth 2.0](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/) protocol controls authorization to access a protected resource, like your web app, native app, or API service.

In both cases it's a matter of proper [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), i.e. see [OpenID Connect - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-jmeter) for example challenge and solution.